# How to count Firebase child items that match a certain criteria

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For each user account I'm trying to count how many events they have today.

My data is structured as follows:

```
accounts -
{
 "-KaxcGWx1-a8s7dhsjhsd" : {
 "name" : "Bill",
 "events" : [ {
  "event" : "-KdHscYor4mA--ubIHBj"
 }, {
  "event" : "-KdKsJBdHimgPPQQ6bcA"
 } ],
 },
 "-KaxcGWx1-rA2anjKI4h" : {
 "name" : "Bob",
 "username" : "Bob"
 "events" : [ {
  "event" : "-KdHscYor4mA--ubIHBj"
 }]
 }
}


events -
{
 "-KdHscYor4mA--ubIHBj" : {
   "dateCreated" : "Fri Feb 17 2017 23:37:32 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
   "eventDate" : "2017-04-01",
   "name" : "Event 1",
},
 "-KdKsJBdHimgPPQQ6bcA" : {
   "dateCreated" : "Fri Feb 17 2017 23:37:32 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
   "eventDate" : "2017-04-01",
   "name" : "Event 2",
 }
 }
```

So given that both events are for today. I would expect to Bill to have two and Bob to have one.

The code I have tried is:

```
var todayDate = '2017-04-01';
var ref = firebase.database().ref('accounts/');
ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    //Foreach user account
    var eventCount = 0;
    snapshot.forEach(function (account) {
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + account.key);
        ref.child('events').once('value', function (eventSnapshot) {
            //Foreach event
            eventSnapshot.forEach(function (child) {
                firebase.database().ref('events/' + child.val().event).once('value', function (event) {
                        if (eventDate === todayDate) {
                            console.log(account.val().name, 'has an event today -', event.val().name);
                            eventCount++;
                        }
                });
            });    
        });
        console.log(account.val().name, 'total events -', eventCount);
    });
});
```

However, the result I'm getting in the console is:

```
Bill total events - 0
Bob total events - 0
Bill has an event today Event 1
Bill has an event today Event 2
Bob has an event today Event 2
```

Comment: Nothing in the data structure you show is a date. Please add the actual JSON (as text), which you can get by clicking Export JSON in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Also make sure that your code snippet is completely self-contained. As it now is, we have no way of knowing what `todayDate` and `eventDate` are. It might be a good idea to reproduce the problem in a small jsbin and then link that from your question.

Comment: The eventDate is arbitrary. I simplified my example code, but I'll try to get a jsbin example. The date matching works fine. The issue appears to be that the callback is triggered before the snapshot.forEach has completed. And this seems to be why the console logs the events in apparently the wrong order

Comment: Are u using the account name as key?

Comment: I've updated with Firebase Json exports of events and accounts. I think the problem is more to do with Firebase promises and callbacks
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html

Comment: As Doug and Adolfo said, your current data structure won't work well for this use-case. With NoSQL databases you'll often find yourself structuring the data to allow the use-cases of your app. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen those links are super useful as I've come from a SQL/MySQL background so structuring data within NoSQL is still relatively new to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the general structure of your code. You're deeply nesting calls to ref.once('value') and expecting them all to execute synchronously.  However, once() is asynchronous.  That function always returns immediately - it does not wait for the snapshot.  Sometime later, whenever the data is available, your callback is called with the snapshot.  This means your foreach loops are iterating each child of the snapshot and finishing before any of your snapshot callbacks are called.  And that results in your counts being 0.

You're going to need to completely restructure your code in an event-driven asynchronous fashion rather than the procedural synchronous way you have it now.

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of making sense. I was trying to figure out Firebase promises and callbacks but am still getting lost. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html

Comment: Yes, your code could structured in a way that's easier to understand using promises.  It's common to "chain" calls to the then() method on a sequence of promises for each stage of your processing.

Answer (score 0):

With your current structure you will have problems when scaling because you would need to retrieve all the users and then all time events for that user and check each one of the dates. You could do it much simpler by changing your events data structure a bit.

```
events: {
  eventId1: {
   date: '20170401',
   attendingAccount:{
     accountId1: true,
     accountId2: true,
   }
  },
  eventId2: {...}
}
```

If you just save the `accountId` of the users that are attending the event like above you would just need to run something like the following:

```
let attendingCount = {};

firebase.database().ref('events').orderByChild('date').equalTo(today).once(snap => {
    let events = snap.val();

    if (events){
        Object.keys(events).forEach(eventId => {
            Object.keys(events[eventId].attendingAccounts).forEach(accountId => {
                if (!attendingCount[accountId]){
                    attendingCount[accountId] = 0;
                }
                attendingCount[accountId]++;
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This would result in the object `attendingCount` having the count for each one of the accountIds.

```
attendingCount: {
   accountId1: 2,
   accountId2: 5,
   ...
}
```